# or operation in yii mongo suite or direct mongo suite

Tags: mongodb, yii

I am having a problem with mongo db when used in yii framework. I tried both yii extensions yii mong suite and direct mongo suite. I have trouble implementing or operations in mongo with these extension. I used this code in yii mongo suite but its returning all the values.

```
$userDetail = $user->findAll(
              array(
            '$or' => array(
               "first_name" => "akash",
               "first_name" => "anoop"
         )
       )
   );   var_dump($userDetail);die;
```

I dont know how to use or operation with direct mongo suite. Please help me as soon as possible. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

With the direct MongoDBSuite, providing it implements MongoDB directly, your `$or` should look like:

```
$userDetail = $user->findAll(
    array(
        '$or' => array(
            array("first_name" => "akash"),
            array("first_name" => "anoop")
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: with direct mongo suite I call the result using 
$result = EDMSQuery::instance('users')->findArray($criteria,$select);
in here where should i give the or operation.                  $criteria = array('$or',array('personal_no'=>1234),array('personal_no'=>1235);

Answer (score 0):

I know this is pretty late but let me know if this helps. I'm using YiiMongoDbSuite. You could check to see if the name is in an array.

$criteria = new EMongoCriteria;
$criteria->addCond("first_name","in",array("akash", "anoop"));

Read more here about using the EMongoCriteria Object: http://bit.ly/1oOFPBJ